# array of objects always return 0 ,although it has more than one object inside

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-redux, return-value, react-state

I'm getting data from react-redux and want to disable the button if the number of array items is ===0. but I always getting the value of 0 from myPetArray.length ,although  it has more than one element inside it ,and I'm able to verify that as you see in image below the console show 0 element inside array but redux dev tools show real data (two object inside array)
[image: console]
[image: redux dev tools]

thank you :)

```
const dispatch = useDispatch()
```

//status of the next button

```
const [nextButton, setNextButton] = useState(false)
```

//part of state that return myPetArray

```
const petListByUserId = useSelector((state) => state.petListByUserId)
  const { myPetArray, myPetArraySuccess } = petListByUserId
   
    
     useEffect(() => {

    dispatch(getPetListByUserId(userId))

     if (myPetArray && myPetArray.length === 0) {
      console.log(mypetArray.length)
      setNextButton(true)
    }
    
  }, [userId,myPetArray ])
  
  
    <Button disabled={nextButton}>Next Step</Button>
```

Comment: Could you please log your `petListByUserId`?

Comment: Object { myPetArray: [] }
​
myPetArray: Array []
​​
length: 0
​​
<prototype>: Array []
​
<prototype>: Object { … }

Comment: Your `myPetArray` obviously has nothing in it?

Comment: at the beginning it is an empty array. Good point...thank you...let me check. But I'm able see the value inside redux dev tools....any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but it might be worth trying:

```
console.log(mypetArray[0].length)
```